# How to stop GDB stepping in to system calls?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

I've updated Ubuntu to newest version. But when I use GDB to debug program found that when input <kbd>s</kbd> all the way, GDB will step into the implementation of system calls, `printf()`, for example. So what to do to prevent GDB stepping into system calls when I input <kbd>s</kbd>?

Comment: It's not very clear why you consider this to be a problem, you're asking the debugger to single-step and somehow expecting it not to? Also, `printf()` is not a "system call", it's a call into the standard library.

Comment: yes that's what i mean,I don't want it to step into standard library functions.What to do？thanks~

Comment: WOW!  It seems that gdb cannot step over function calls?  That would be incredibly lame:(

Comment: Someone tell me it's not true:(

Comment: @unwind 'It's not very clear why you consider this to be a problem' - you joketh, surely?  Step in and step over are core functonalities for a debugger!

Comment: OK 'next' does it,  Relief....

Comment: before I update the OS,in GDB input 's' means step into,but won't step into the standard library.In the new GDB,input 's' can step into standard library functions which I don't want to,I just want to step into the user defined functions.So now when encounter standard library functions I must change 's' to 'n' and then change back to 's',which bothers me.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?